# Display embedded doc / docx / pdf inside HTML using Google APIs

Tags: google-api, docx, google-api-client, google-docs-api, doc

I have a problem to display doc / docx / pdf docs assuming I have an online link to them (i.e. http://my.site.com/files/file_id_123423234)

2 Alternative I know Google provide are 2 following links:

1. http://docs.google.com/gview?url=[link_to_file]

   Example:
   http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://my.site.com/files/file_id_123423234&embedded=true
2. https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=[link_to_file]

   Example:
   https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=http://my.site.com/files/file_id_123423234&embedded=true

Both alternatives not always manage to successfully display the doc ending up the http call with "no preview available":
[image]

Can you please provide a solution / alternative?

Comment: Can you please provide me the link to the API where you got these options from? I'm using Docs Viewer to embed docs in my site and want to know what are the other options like url and embed available.

Comment: @karthikaruna, I didnt found any API documentation. only examples here in StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make use of the Embedded links. To do this, you have to publish the files on the web as stated in [Publish and embed Google Docs, Sheets, Slides & Forms](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=en).

File -> Publish to the Web. Get the Embed Link.